# SSRS stacked bar chart multiple series, utilizing category groups for different date fields

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, stackedbarseries, reporting-services-2012

The source data is a SSAS cube, which contains information about tickets, particularly **priority**, **date opened**, and **date closed**.
Each ticket has a priority and date opened value, though the closed value may be null or another placeholder value (subject to change).
A ticket is represented by a record in the source table with the mentioned attributes, and in the cube each of the dates are linked to a date dimension record (with the exception of the potentially null closed date).
I utilize a named-set to limit the data from the cube to the past 13 months.

The desired result is a multiple column stacked bar chart, the Series Grouping should be Priority thereby creating the stack with Y-axis representing a ticket count dependent on the X-axis which is a grouping by month.
Each month grouping should have a stack dependent on the opened and closed dates.

The closest I've come is utilizing the category expressions but I have beginners knowledge in this.

Any suggestions in either the way I'm pulling the dataset from the cube with MDX to alleviate the creation of the chart or features of the SSRS chart control are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exhaustive investigation, it seems that this is a common problem when using Role-Playing Dimensions in your OLAP cube. That is multiple joins from a single fact back to a single dimension. For example when attempting to generate a report with Date on an axis, where the Date dimension is the Role-Playing Dimension, there is a non-user friendly experience.

This article helped in providing a solution to modeling the data in a slight different way.

http://visual-intelligence.nu/how-to-avoid-role-playing-dimensions-in-ssas/